# IPv6 Telegram setWebhook got "Reserved" message

Tags: telegram, iot, ipv6

```
curl -6 https://api.telegram.org/bot440785422:AAHWflhfXmFT6A1wulp92GXdsftoOQ2IjFg/setWebhook?url=https://v6.eipa.ru/tt.pl
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: bad webhook: IP 2001:470:b38c:0:6e71:d1ff:fe63:5cda is reserved"}
```

I'm using ipv6 to my web server and i've got message - Bad Request: bad webhook: IP is reserved. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Supports IPv4, IPv6 is currently not supported for [webhooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#the-short-version).